# High server load with Curl (and usleep)

Tags: php, curl, libcurl

I'm facing very high load averages when performing a high number of curl multi requests.

Basically we have a platform that for each visit it will 20-40 requests to remote feeds (low latency, response time is less than 800ms). I've tested every part of the platform and the only one that seems to create the bottleneck is curl.

Our code is as follows:

```
foreach ($connomains as $i => $url)
    {
        $conn[$i] = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($conn[$i], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($conn[$i], CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_setopt($conn[$i], CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt($conn[$i], CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE,0);
        curl_setopt($conn[$i], CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, 0);
        curl_setopt($conn[$i], CURLOPT_INTERFACE,$interface);

        global $countrycode;
        curl_setopt($conn[$i], CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS, 1*500 ); 
        curl_setopt($conn[$i], CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT_MS, 500 );
        curl_setopt($conn[$i], CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL, 1); 
        curl_multi_add_handle ($mh,$conn[$i]);
    }

    do
    {
        $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
        //usleep(1);  // I've tried with a usleep here as well, no difference
    }while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);

    while ($active and $mrc == CURLM_OK)
    {
        if (curl_multi_select($mh, $active) != -1)
        {
            do
            {
                $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
            } while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);
        }
        else
        {
            usleep(10); // This doesn't seem to make any difference either.
        }       
    }
```

Our Curl configuration: (built with c-ares)

curl-config --features --protocols
SSL
IPv6
UnixSockets
AsynchDNS
NTLM
NTLM_WB
HTTPS-proxy
DICT
FILE
FTP
FTPS
GOPHER
HTTP
HTTPS
IMAP
IMAPS
POP3
POP3S
SMB
SMBS
SMTP
SMTPS
TELNET
TFTP

So basically on our stress tests, what happens after sending a certain amount of traffic, the load average goes beyond 100 and curl starts taking more than 10 seconds to reply (with a 500ms timeout). I've tried everything that came to my mind already. Any ideas here?

Thanks in advance.